# Checkbox button in table view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, checkbox

I want to create a check box in each row in in tableview. My code works for only one checkbox. If  i have more than 1 it fails. My code is

```
  UIButton   * checkBox=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkBox.tag=indexPath.row;
        checkBox.frame=CGRectMake(270,15, 20, 20);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
        [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWith.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender{
if(self.isChecked ==NO){
  self.isChecked =YES;
  [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"selectedBoxWithTik.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else
{
   self.isChecked =NO;
  [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWith.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

How can I handle it for more checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to try this. It will work..........

```
-(void)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender{

    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

    if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWith.png"]]) {
        [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"selectedBoxWithTik.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWith.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i fine which button is checked?for example can i take the row value of checked button

Comment: just add this one line code to your cellForRowAtndexPath function :-   checkBox.tag = [indexPath row];   now just check for sender.tag where you need to know about checked button row like this:  if([[sender currentImage] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]])

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply do this by using a simple `UIButton` as you will be needing to detect which row number checkbox was pressed. Hence instead of using a `UIButton` directly use a `CustomButton` which extends UIButton and has an extra property `rowTag` like:

```
@interface CustomButton : UIButton {
  NSInteger rowTag;
}

@property NSInteger rowTag;

@end

@implementation CustomButton

@synthesize rowTag;

@end
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if(cell==nil){
        CustomButton   * checkBox=[CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkBox.tag=21;
        checkBox.frame=CGRectMake(270,15, 20, 20);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
        [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
    CustomButton *btn = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:21];
    [btn setRowTag:indexPath.row];
    if(selectedProperty){
       [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWithTik.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
       [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBoxWith.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Example, click on first row is used to change for other rows. Click on other rows only change itself. arrCheckbox is an array used to store check of all rows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"AV--%s", __func__);
    HistoryCell2 *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Create new row");
        [tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HistoryCell2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellId];
        cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
    }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    BOOL checked =  [[arrCheckbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_on.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_off.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 29, 29);
    button.frame = frame;   // match the button's size with the image size
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}

- (void) checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    int index = (int)tappedButton.tag;
    NSLog(@"Row button: %d", index);

    if(index > 0)
    {
        BOOL checked = [[arrCheckbox objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];
        [arrCheckbox removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [arrCheckbox insertObject:(checked) ? @"0":@"1" atIndex:index];

        UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_off.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_on.png"];
        [tappedButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        //UITableView *tableview = (UITableView *)[[tappedButton superview] superview];
        UIImage *newImage;
        BOOL checked = [[arrCheckbox objectAtIndex:0] boolValue];
        for(int i=0; i<[arrCheckbox count]; i++)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Row: %d------", i);
            [arrCheckbox removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [arrCheckbox insertObject:(checked) ? @"0":@"1" atIndex:i];

            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            for(UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
            {
                if([subview isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
                {
                    //NSLog(@"Modify button");
                    tappedButton = (UIButton*)subview;
                    //[subview removeFromSuperview];
                    newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_off.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"cb_on.png"];
                    [tappedButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```